# what is the best way to display website visitors a one time welcome message?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, css

I've got a website, and I want to add a welcoming message which hovers on a certain part of the page which only loads for the visitor for the first time they login, and won't again(presumably cookies used). And says something like "adjust your settings here.."
I don't want it to be an external popup but something that loads on the page in a certain area, defined by me (PX-pixle reference)

What would be the best coding language to do it in, oes anyone have any examples of this, or any site based generators to make it on?
thanks

Comment: Do you want to stored into your system or client browser

Comment: Any language is able to do that. It's just some HTML to include or not in the page. If you already have a login procedure, that means that you're already using a server-side language. Use what you already use.

Comment: Additional note: don't use a cookie for that, since a cookie is tight to a specific browser on a specific machine. You want this to occur only one time for a given user: store a flag in your database for each user, indicating if he has already logged in or not.

Comment: ok so i'm thinking adding it to the database, so it only happens once per a user, how do i set this up? and would I use a image to load or would i get javascript etc to load/generate it?
thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Create one more field in database with `lastlogin`.
When user is created then make `lastlogin` field with `special`.

When user signs the next time from `Login Page`, update the field the `lastlogin` value to `regular`

//query to get value of `lastlogin`

//add css to elements you want to hover

```
<element class="<?php if($last-login == 'sepcial') { echo 'sepcialcss'; } else {echo 'regularcss'; }">
```

Done in PHP

Comment: Why use the IP of the user if the message must be displayed after he logs in? If he has logged in, the serevr knows who he is, and its IP address (which can be different at each login) doesn't matter.

Comment: Well Great!! It's a good answer and don't use cookies or sessions!

Answer (score 1):

As you added the tag, `php` would do this, actually any language will do.

Generally you have two ways to do this.

1. Do it on your server.
2. Do it on client's computer.

for the first way, you check the cookies and generate the page you want.
for the second way, you need to arrange the page the visitors see with `java script`.

way 1 recommended, coz it loads less bits. LOL

Update:

your server supports `php` right? the page, say it `index.php`, has a special area which is different when the visitors login the first time, right?

```
<?php
    if (firstLogin()){
        genSpecial();
    }
    else{
        genRegular();
    }
?>
```

in the funcition `firstLogin()`, you shall read the cookies and determine.
in the other two functions, just gen two different part, i.e. some html source code.
to your question, if you need to load some image, do it in `genSpecial()`. and if you choose the first way, js is not used to gen the special area, it's used only if in the special area, there needs some js.

Comment: Ok, so how would i set it up on the server? and would i get it to load a image or generate something from javascript etc?
thanks

Comment: ok thanks for everything so far, really helps, so would it look something like this,
`code`  also how do I ipmlement a little close button in it to close the message?

`code` 
<?php
    if (firstLogin()){
        genSpecial(load = css file  buffer 500px top, 300px left);
    }
    else{
        genRegular();
    }
?>
`code`

Comment: how would i load something jquaery dialog? for this aplication

Comment: @David load it as common html, in ```genSpecial()```

Comment: hi @Topro thanks for the reply, so bassically, add everything to load to the `genspecial()` ?

Comment: @David yes, put all the html(include js) in the ```genSpecial()```

Comment: ok thanks i'm with you now, one thing though, my site doesn't have a separate page for first time login, it's the same page if you login the first time, or if you login the 50th time, so how would i implement this?
thanks

Comment: @David yeah, ```genSpecial()``` just produce a part of that page, as you said the "adjust your setting here" stuff

Comment: ok great, you've been super helpful, would i be able to make it in jquerie (the message box) with a little dismiss button in the corner?
thanks

Comment: @David as i said, put all the jquery stuff in ```genSpecial()```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through javascript. Once the user is shown the settings, store the result in a cookie valid for as long as you want. The next time the user logs in, verify if the cookie is set and then proceed.

Sample code to create cookies:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for more details on how to create and use cookies

Comment: i'm thinking i want to set it up so it only appears once per a user, rather than a machine, how would I set this up on the server?

Comment: Well, in that case, storing those variables (for settings) in a database is a good way to go. If the value is set in the database, don't show the settings. Use PHP. Set the variables to null initially. `if($data['settings']!=null){//do something}`

Comment: what if cookies are deleted from browser, then user logins with first time options.